# Android customizing Toolbar for Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I'm trying to implement a Material style ActionBar using toolbar. So far I made a working Material style ActionBar but can't change its icon and text color. I've already set a

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

in style.xml and

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
```

as the toolbar theme.

Is there any way to change the text color and the black icons into the white ones?

Sources are given below,

Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.materialactionabar.MainActivity" >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.example.materialactionabar.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your styles just add as below:

```
<item name="spinBars">true</item>
<item name="color">@color/white</item>
```

Complete code as below:

```
<resources>
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ranjith, Got it working properly. I have a small question why do we need to add another style to the main theme? I mean it suppose to work without adding a new style.